# Best practice emberJS for controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have this structure in my routes.

```
this.resource('stations',  function() {
   this.route('view', {path: ':name'});
   this.route('edit', {path: ':name/edit'});
   this.route('create', {path: ':name/create'});
});
```

I have these controllers

```
App.StationsEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   actions: {
      editStation: function() {
        //Logic for edit Station
      }
   }
});

App.StationsCreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   actions: {
      createStation: function() {
        //Logic for create Station
      }
   }
});
```

Please can you tell me if this is good practice?

Also I would like to just use one controller called stations with a list of my actions that all of my views within that controller can call? For Example: -

```
App.StationsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   actions: {
      createStation: function() {
        //Logic for create Station
      }
      editStation: function() {
        //Logic for create Station
      }
   }
});
```

Open to ideas about this scenario.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have your controllers set up is considered the norm, so yes, it's good practice. :)

However, combining the actions in a single controller won't work like that. Actions have a specific bubbling path. They try the route's controller first, then the route, then they bubble up the route hierarchy. They do *not* bubble up the controller hierarchy. So if you wanted to put the actions together like that, you'd have to define the actions in your `StationsRoute`, not your `StationsController`.

Comment: Alex Speller has a great explanation of where to put model logic/actions in your Ember App: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/where-should-i-define-a-save-action/5062